# convex and concave regions

Tags: functions

I was doing this question and it quoted that "Given that the region OCB is convex..." but surely that region is concave as a basic way is that a line between two points can be drawn under the curve. It is something to do with the fact it says region? [image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a more consistent definition of the terms:

- A region is convex $\implies$ the segment between any two distinct points of the region is completely included in the shape (the segment is a subset of the region).
- A region is concave $\implies$ at least one segment between two different points is not fully included in the region (it is partly outside of it - the segment is not a subset of the region)

See the picture* below for clarifications.

[image: region]

<sub>*Source: Wolfram MathWorld</sub>

And in your case:

[image: graph]

Comment: is it just convention that a region below a concave function is named convex or is there a logical explanation why

Comment: Yes, you may say it as so @Labracad

Comment: Aside there is a logical reason, see the definitions.

Comment: id have thought it was the other way round as showing that a line fits inside the curve shows its convex

Comment: @Labracad you thought the other way around. Sorry, cannot replace convensions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, convex *region* is something else as the interval where the `function` (its 1-D *curve*) is convex.

Convex region means convex 2-D `shape` - i. e. for every 2 points *A*, *B* of it the full line segment `AB` is its subset.

Comment: can you look at the question please. Surely that is concave function, not convex. So am I right in thinking it is wrong?

Comment: You are right - and me to. (Can you look at my answer, please :-)) You *region* (2-D) is convex but you part of *function* (1-D) is concave.

Comment: how is part of the function convex

Comment: It is *not* a part of your function which is convex - it is the *shape* delimited by the segments OC, OB and the curve BC (of your function graph).

Comment: what does delimited mean

Comment: That I's its border - you are right, the term *region OCB* in your task is - from math point of view - something vague. Precise definition would be - "a set of all [x,y] where x>=0 ... and so on".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59039/discussion-between-labracad-and-mariand).